# What should our custom close reasons be?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Right now, if you are voting to close a question, the *off topic because...* menu only contains three items:

- This question does not appear to be about woodworking, within the scope defined in the [help center](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help).
- This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network
- Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)

On other beta sites, there can be up to five entries, if I'm not mistaken. ([Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) has seven currently, but SO is running a highly customized version of the Stack Exchange software stack, while the beta sites all run on the same "standardized" version.)

The last two items seem to be standard across all sites, so we have three items to play with. What would you like to see there?

<sup>Please note that the text of the top item will appear if a question is put on hold for a custom reason (the "Other" choice), so it's kind of redundant.</sup>

Comment: I'm going to close this question for much the same reason I outlined in this thread: http://meta.woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/30/what-is-off-topic-for-woodworking#comment62_30. Starting a question from the premise of anticipating all the ways users can suck at this site is somewhat backwards. Enjoy your site, and if problems arise, ***then*** you can address them each in their own meta thread to see if further actions are warranted. But creating a catch-all *"add your rules here"* thread is not the tone we should be setting so early in this site.

Answer (score 2):

I think that *currently* our scope is just building and it would be too early to define new close reasons now. At least I don't remember any SE site that would have had defined new close reasons in the first day of its existence.

Remember that you can still choose "custom" off-topic close reason in the close dialogue and it would be shown to others in the section "off-topic" who want to close that question as off-topic.

Choosing the custom reason also automatically creates a comment from you. That's because when the question is closed, you'll see just "This question does not appear to be about woodworking, within the scope defined in the help center." in the notice, so the comment is actually quite useful for anyone who wants to understand the reason of closure better.

Comment: part of that is the custom close reasons come from repeated off topic questions, like the countless questions asking for what language to pick on SO.

Comment: This is correct. We shouldn't be enumerating all the possible ways you can go wrong on this site and then creating a list of rules in anticipation of stopping them. You start by identifying a recurring problem that is happening **in actual practice** and then, over time, you decide if the problem is prevalent enough to warrant more explicit actions. But until that happens, **be wary of SEEKING out new rules** simply for the sake of having them.